# Too many configurations

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

Whenever I try to import my products (with about 15000-16000 configurations) and try to open it in the backend, I get an error saying:

> Cdata section too big

Frontend works just fine after caching is refreshed(which takes about 3 minutes).
I know that is a lot of configurations, but what can I do to make it work?

I have 30 products of this kind and need to have a stable and smooth experience in front and backend. Is there maybe a better way to organize the products?

Comment: How about you split the import? How many configurations are bound to a product?

Comment: The import itself works fine. The configurations are bound to exactly that one product.

Comment: see http://php.net/manual/de/domdocument.loadxml.php#113676 and https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/4695

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We've open sourced our solution for using configurable products with an extremely large amount of associated simple products; https://github.com/elgentos/LargeConfigProducts, which has a workaround for this issue.

Comment: This workaround is still needed in Magento 2.3 ?

Comment: Unfortunately yes.

Comment: @PeterJaapBlaakmeer While installing this extension facing the issue `Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages. - Conclusion: don't install composer/composer 1.8.6`.  check the details error here https://i.imgur.com/lmxFaJ7.png

Comment: @Narayan the composer name is `elgentos/largeconfigproducts` (with lowercase letters)